# Inquiry to mongoDB aggregate return me result empty array, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Why did this query work on my Robo 3T? but not in nodejs. Inquiry return me result null, where in Robo return my results.

But if I have

```
ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")
```

But in NodeJS I have error :

> Possibly unhandled rejection:
>
> ## ObjectId is not defined
>
> ```
> ReferenceError:
>   ObjectId is not defined
> ```

If I change for

```
'ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")'
```

I have result array null, Can someone tell me how to save that??

NodeJS :

`router.get('/usercards', function (req, res) {
var pipeline =
  [
    {
      "$project": { 
          "name":1,
        "boardcards": {
          "$reduce": {
            "input": "$lists.cards",
            "initialValue": [ ],
            "in": { "$concatArrays": [ "$$value", {
            "$filter": {
               "input": "$$this",
               "as": "result",
                "cond": { "$in": [ 'ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d")', {"$ifNull":["$$result.Author", []]} ]}
            }
         } 
         ] 
         }
          }
        }
      }

    },
       {
    "$unwind": "$boardcards"
  }  

  ];

  Board.aggregate(pipeline, function (err, result){
    if (err) res.send(err);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 4));
    res.send(result);
}) 
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Node you need to use : `var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`
Then use your pipeline query.

If you are using mongoose then:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
schema1 = mongoose.model('schema'),
mongoose.Types.ObjectId("<object_id>")

schema1.find({"_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("<object_id>")}, function 
(err, record) {
  // Do stuff
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much !, Can u tell me one more thing if I have : "cond": { "$in": [ ObjectId("59df60fb6fad6224f4f9f22d"), {"$ifNull":["$$result.Author", []]} ]}, ,, ,, so can I replace objectId with id with variable ?? for example req.body._id ??

Comment: It would be better to pass in ObjectId(req.body._id)